# Oracle Database Security - Audit Trail for specific user and specific module application

Tags: oracle, security, audit

I want to enable audit trail for specific user, but only for sessions when this user connect to database using one specific module applications.

For ex. I want to enable audit trail for user *test1* only when user *test1* is connected to database using **TOAD**, but not when the user *test1* is connected to database using **Golden6**.

Is this type of audit possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Would a trace do?  You could activate that using a logon trigger.  But watch out, if he's using Toad or not, how are you going to make sure?  What if he renames the executable to Golden6?   https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154937/oracle-auditing-on-specific-user-activity

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Unified Auditing, which is available starting with version 12.1.

Example:

```
create user u1 identified by u1 quota unlimited on users;
grant create session, create table to u1;
grant audit_viewer to u1;
```

Now create a Unified Audit policy, that audits all actions when the user is `U1`, and module is not `Golden6`:

```
create audit policy mypolicy1
actions all 
when 'sys_context(''userenv'', ''current_user'') = ''U1'' and sys_context(''userenv'', ''module'') != ''Golden6'''
evaluate per statement
;

SQL> audit policy mypolicy1;

Audit succeeded.
```

Then test it:

```
SQL> conn u1/u1
Connected.

SQL> select sys_context('userenv', 'current_user') as current_user, sys_context('userenv', 'module') as module from dual;

CURRENT_USER         MODULE
-------------------- --------------------
U1                   SQL*Plus

SQL> create table t1 (c1 number);

Table created.

SQL> exec dbms_application_info.set_module('Golden6', null);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> create table t2 (c1 number);

Table created.

SQL> exec dbms_application_info.set_module('SQL*Plus', null);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> create table t3 (c1 number);

Table created.
```

Now check the contents of the audit trail:

```
SQL> select event_timestamp, DBUSERNAME, ACTION_NAME, sql_text, RETURN_CODE from unified_audit_trail where dbusername = 'U1' and sql_text like 'create%' order by event_timestamp;

EVENT_TIMESTAMP                DBUSERNAME ACTION_NAME          SQL_TEXT                       RETURN_CODE
------------------------------ ---------- -------------------- ------------------------------ -----------
17-APR-18 02.04.29.381770 PM   U1         CREATE TABLE         create table t1 (c1 number)              0
17-APR-18 02.04.59.233856 PM   U1         CREATE TABLE         create table t3 (c1 number)              0
```

As you can see, the creation of table `t2` statement, that was issued with the module set to `Golden6`, was not audited.

Comment: I have created the policy, but after I check the contents of the audit trail  'unified_audit_trail'  doesn't return any value!

Comment: Hi Balazs Papp,

I want to do exactly the same thing but unfortunatelly we run on 11.2 database.
Is there any possibility to do the same fonctionality in 11.2

Best

Answer (score 0):

Oracle `unified_audit_trail` view keeps track on `client_program_name` of the audited actions and `Toad.exe` can be found there along the others. `Sys_context` makes it possible to make audit policy conditions that take some session parameters into consideration, but there seem to be none for the `client_program_name` (`client_info` is not the same) - wonder where the uat finds the information?

More about `sys_context` here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions165.htmpo